# Command ntile in R

Tags: r, quantile

I have the following data

```
 [1]  1.400  0.100 11.600 20.980  0.250  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000  0.000 13.400  7.800 15.690  1.200  1.900  0.900  2.800 12.300  0.000
  [20] 20.320  0.270 16.730 17.460 12.050  0.300 19.400  9.500 19.870 52.870 20.700 24.300  0.700  3.800  8.770 17.000  4.500 16.490  8.610
  [39]  9.670 18.100 25.300 11.600 16.700  3.000  5.500  8.900 11.100 16.200 17.200  2.500 13.800  7.600  0.500  0.660  6.100 17.000  2.200
  [58]  3.800  1.800 17.900 15.000  0.200 12.000  0.600  5.200  0.000  0.000  0.000  2.100  0.300 34.400  4.710  1.500 10.000  0.300  0.800
  [77]  7.700  2.500  0.000  6.500  4.600  0.600 17.700  5.800 10.800 17.300  2.400 10.000 27.400  0.000  8.600  3.200  4.400  0.000  0.100
  [96]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 12.800  0.000  0.500  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.100  1.300  0.000  6.500  0.800  0.000  2.200  2.200  2.200
 [115]  0.000  1.500  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.700  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  3.900  5.200  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 15.000  2.300
```

What I want to do is to create a new column and asign a "0" for the columns of data 0 and a ntile for the rest. I would thank your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand how you want to put the ntiles in the vector, but this snippet might help achieve what you are trying to do (I create a new random vector just for the concept of it):

```
vec = rnorm(200,10,5)
vec[vec<0]=0

cuts = c((1:10)/10) ## define ntile cuts. Here: .1 to 1.0 in 10 steps
q = quantile(vec,cuts)

ntiles = rep(0,length(vec))
for(i in length(cuts):1){
  ntiles[vec<=q[i]]=cuts[i]
}
```

The result is a translation of the original vector to a representation of the quantile of each point:

```
plot(vec,ntiles)
```

[image: Scatterplot]

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I want to do is to assign a value between 1 and 52 for the values greater than 0 and 0 for the values equal as 0.

Comment: Not randomly, but like a group of intervals.

Comment: @CésarCarvallo, in that case, just set the cuts to 52 values between 0 and 1: `cuts = c((1:52)/52)` . That should work.